# Why can't I insert an object into set firebase.firestore Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I actually can insert data with Maps but I can't with objects from my own classes. When in firestore documentation they say that I can.

The error is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No properties to serialize found on class com.example.alumne.rateit.core.model.Restaurant
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
class Restaurant(name: String, fiscName: String, cif: String, addr: String, city: String, phone: String, zipCode: String, country: String, email: String): Serializable{ }

override fun onClick(view: View?) {
    when(view?.id){
        btn_submit.id ->{
            if (checkForEmptyField()){
                val restName = et_rest_name.text.toString()
                val restFiscName = et_fiscal_name.text.toString()
                val restAddr = et_address.text.toString()
                val restPhone = et_phone.text.toString()
                val restZipCode = et_zip_code.text.toString()
                val restCif = et_cif.text.toString()
                val restCity = et_city.text.toString()
                val restCountry = et_country.text.toString()
                val restEmail = et_email.text.toString()

                /*val restaurant: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()
                restaurant.put("name",restName)
                restaurant.put("fiscName",restFiscName)
                restaurant.put("address",restAddr)
                restaurant.put("phone",restPhone)
                restaurant.put("zipCode",restZipCode)
                restaurant.put("cif",restCif)
                restaurant.put("city",restCity)
                restaurant.put("country",restCountry)
                restaurant.put("email",restEmail)*/

                val rest = Restaurant(restName,restFiscName,restCif,restAddr,restCity,restPhone,restZipCode,restCountry,restEmail)
                if (bd.collection("restaurants").document().set(rest).isSuccessful){
                    Utilities.showMessage(view,"Restaurant added correctly")
                }else{
                    Utilities.showMessage(view,"Error adding restaurant")
                }
            }else{
                if (view != null) {
                    Utilities.showMessage(view,"Fill all fields")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error you are receiving that will help

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: No properties to serialize found on class com.example.alumne.rateit.core.model.Restaurant

Comment: extend the Restaurant class with Serializable.

Comment: Show us `Restaurant`: The error said it contains no properties to serialize it...

Comment: I've already tryed this solution, but nothing :(

Comment: class Restaurant(name: String, fiscName: String, cif: String, addr: String, city: String, phone: String, zipCode: String, country: String, email: String): Serializable{

}

Comment: Please edit your question to show the contents of your Restaurant class.  Also, bear in mind that the set() method is async and returns an unresolved Task, and you need to attach listeners to that Task to know when it's finished.

Comment: Please edit your question to add contents of your Restaurant class.

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?hl=en)

> Each custom class must have a public constructor that takes no arguments. In addition, the class must include a public getter for each property.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't accept objects for set method.
You can simply use an interface or convert your class object into an interface as follows.
Create an Interface and Class like this.

```
export interface IUser {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  id: string;
}
export class User implements IUser {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  id: string;
  constructor(args) {
    this.name = args.name;
    this.email = args.email;
    this.id = args.id;
  }
}
```

Then, you convert your object into interface instance with

```
var userData = new User({
    name: "user",
    email: "user@gmail.com",
    id: ":LKJDFasdfFSDsadfhAdfsf76dfasdf",
});

var user: IUser = <IUser>JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userData));
```

You can use this User model in the set method.

```
this.firestore.collection('users').doc(this.userData.id).set(user);
```

For more information, visit Firestore official docs :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data